# UIScrollView resetting contentOffset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView whose content offset resets itself all the time for some random reason. Has anyone ever encountered this issue? I had the content offset to 100 and then it resets back scrolling to the top. Any way to prevent this?

So here's the code/hack that I did to make it work in setting the contentOffset:

```
 [self.currentViewController_ performSelector:@selector(scrollToOffset:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

and in my currentViewController class I have

```
-(void)scrollToOffset: (CGFloat) yOffset
{
    [[self.webView_ defaultScrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -44) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Show us some code dude! Particularly the method that sets the contentOffset and any of the scroll view delegate methods you may have implemented.

Comment: Obviously, UIScrollView doesn't randomly reset contentOffset most of the time for most people. So you're going to have to tell us more about what's going on *in your app* if you want any hope of a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar problem. In my case, the problem was that I set the content size of the scrollview in viewDidLayoutSubviews. When I tried to scroll the view back programatically, viewDidLayoutSubviews was called and this caused a reset of the content size.

Comment: I also having this problem, is there anyway to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can try stop the back animation when the first animation completes.

Use this delegate call:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

And call this method inside it:

```
   [self setContentOffset:self.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe problem in .contentSize property of your scrollView? Did you set it correct?